# Problems Plotting PCA in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I am currently trying to plot a PCA for my data and when I run the code and have the following issues.

And furthermore, can anyone help take my data and code and produce a PLS-DA? like as in the picture? I couldn't find any good tutorials.

How can I resolve this Issue? The plots should look like:

[image: Text]

So after some help I got this far:

my code:

```
    library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

all_datanoT <- cbind(amino,sphingo,hexose,phospha,lyso,cleaned_xl_Kopie)
all_datawT <- cbind(aminotnos,sphingo,hexose,phospha,lyso,cleaned_xl_Kopie)
rownames(all_datawT) <- sample_id$`Sample Identification`


alldata_naomit <-na.omit(all_datanoT)
all_datawTnaomit <-na.omit(all_datawT)

mypr <- prcomp(log2(alldata_naomit), scale = TRUE)
summary(mypr)

str(mypr)
mypr$x


PC1 <- mypr$x[, 1]
PC2 <- mypr$x[, 2]
pcat <- cbind(all_datawTnaomit, PC1, PC2)



ggplot(  
  data = pcat,
  aes(
    x = PC1,
    y = PC2,
    fill = 'Time point',
    line = 1
  ),
  shape = 1
) +
  geom_point(
    shape = 21,
    colour = "black",
    size = 2,
    stroke = 0.5,
    alpha = 0.6
  ) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  geom_mark_ellipse(
    aes(
      fill = 'Time point',
      color = 'Time point'
    ),
    alpha = 0.05
  )
```

which produces the following plot:

[image: Text]

How can I get it to use the two different Time values for two ellipses T0 and T1? and How can I easily Impute my data so the Na's are replaced by the column means for example instead of ommiting them just so I can plot ?

original Sample Data with dput()

`dput(pcat[sample(nrow(pcat),50)])`

https://gist.github.com/bicvn/47d97929a63ff99e9b260e8658407ae3

new `dput`

https://gist.github.com/bicvn/b06279c6bfa641303b57a3ad2cc07a21

Comment: Could you please `dput(pcat[sample(nrow(pcat),50),])` and add to your question in order to reproduce your issue?

Comment: it is too big to add in edit or as an answer I will try produce a doc with it

Comment: here is a link to the dput https://gist.github.com/bicvn/47d97929a63ff99e9b260e8658407ae3

Comment: Time Point is not present in your new data!!!

Comment: no it is pretty sure, you can find the values T0 and T1 in the dput I posted as well

Comment: my issue is, that I cant get the PC1 and PC2 values out of ```str(mypr)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also check this, here I included an example. The trick use `Comps <- as.data.frame(mypca$x)` to isolate the components and then add to original data. After that you can use `cbind()` with `Comps[,c(1,2)]` to only extract the first two components. Here, I used `iris` dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
#Data
data("iris")
#PCA
mypca <- prcomp(iris[,-5])
#Isolate components
Comps <- as.data.frame(mypca$x)
#Extract components and bind to original data
newiris <- cbind(iris,Comps[,c(1,2)])
#Plot
ggplot(newiris, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, col = Species, fill = Species)) +
  stat_ellipse(geom = "polygon", col= "black", alpha =0.5)+
  geom_point(shape=21, col="black")
```

Output:

[image]

In the case of data shared, only do not apply the NA action. Here the code and output with the data you shared:

```
#Code
ggplot(pcat, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, col = `Time point`, fill = `Time point`)) +
  stat_ellipse(geom = "polygon", col= "black", alpha =0.5)+
  geom_point(shape=21, col="black")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! I will as soon as I can actually use the cbind function properly, as you can read in the other answers comment I get an error there.

Comment: @docelfein Both the original data and the components must have same dimension. Could you please check by first extracting the components in a new dataframe and using `dim()` on both data that are going to be cbinded?

Comment: I edited the question, I na omitted the all_datawT and it worked! but there is another issue

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far, I hope I am not too confusing! just started out using r!

Comment: @docelfein I have added an update, if you have `NA` do not apply the `na.omit()` leave data as it is because `ggplot2` can handle `NA`.

Comment: Thanks you are amazing it worked! The issue is that if i dont ```na.omit```before the ```prcomp()``` I get an error so I think that function can't handle missing values. Do you maybe know a away to impute ```NA``` so I can use all my values ?

Comment: And how could I use my data and code to produce a PLS-DA? as in the picture

Comment: @docelfein Oh I understand. There is way to impute missing values by group using `hotdeck()` function from `VIM` package. You should check that package in order to complete the PCA. Based on the picture, you are closer with what you shared. I think you can create two plots and then use `patchwork` in order to merge them :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221537/discussion-between-doc-elfein-and-duck).

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be discrepancies between your code and your output:

```
pcat <- cbind(all_datawT, mypr$x[, 1:2])
```

adds the first two columns of mypr$x to the data frame. But the output shows:

```
mypr$x[1:2]
```

which is the first two values of the matrix x. If you look at the column, you will see that those two values are repeated down the data. In R this is recycling and it is the default procedure when `cbind` is used to combine vectors that are of different lengths.

The variables `PC1` and `PC2` are not found because you never created any object with those values, e.g.

```
PC1 <- mypr$x[, 1]
PC2 <- mypr$x[, 2]
pcat <- cbind(all_datawT, PC1, PC2)
```

That should work.

Comment: Thanks!! But when I run the ```pcat <- cbind(all_datawT, PC1, PC2)``` I get the following error :   Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  Arguments implicate different number of rows: 90, 35

Comment: Compare `length(PC1)` to `nrow(all_datawT)` . If they are not the same, perhaps there are missing values in the original data? Or you typed `mypr$x[1]` instead of `mypr$x[, 1]`.

Comment: ```PC1``` has a value of 35 while  ```nrow(all_datawT)``` has a value of 90, there are a couple of Na's I want to impute once I know how to but I was using ```na.omit()```to get rid of them, so not sure what to do here

Comment: I edited the question, I na omitted the ```all_datawT``` and it worked! but there is another issue

Comment: I am completely new to r and stackoverflow I hope I am not too confusing! Thanks for all the help so far !!